Flask routing and connexion
I have a flask application where I would like to add Connexion to validate my api endpoints. All api is bundled in a blueprint.
My issue is that Connexion wants to control the routing. Either via connectionid in the OpenApi spec, which I find leaks implementation detail into a specification, or via a class system of automatic routing.
How can i use normal flask routing via decorators together with Connexion?
The following code fails with 500 Internal error.
It works if I uncomment operationId in the OpenAPI spec
This is cxtst.py
from flask import jsonify
from connexion import FlaskApp

app = FlaskApp(__name__)

app.add_api('cxtst.yaml')

@app.route('/test')
def test_fn():
    return jsonify({'output_string': "WORKS"})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)

This is cxtst.yaml
# cxtst.yaml
openapi: 3.0.3
info:
  title: Demonstration of routing in Connexion
  license:
    name: MIT License
    url: https://github.com/Buildasaurus/Factorio-Blueprint-Generator/blob/main/LICENSE
  version: 0.0.1
paths:
  /test:
    get:
      summary: Test that I have access to server
      #operationId: cxtst.test_fn
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Success
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: object
                properties:
                  output_string:
                    type: string


One way to solve this is to decouple/separate routing and request validation. You can configure Connexion to handle the OpenAPI validation but delegate the routing to Flask

Hi Igor. Thank you for your comment, but if you know how, please write an answer on how to do this with connexion.

I added an option below, hopefully it makes sense.

Following up on the discussion in the comments, here's one way to rewrite the code above:
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from connexion import App

flask_app = Flask(__name__)  # a normal, "standard" Flask application as you have it 

# initialize Connexion
app = App(__name__, specification_dir='./')  # change this if needed
app.add_api('cxtst.yaml', validate_responses=True)

@flask_app.route('/test')
def test_fn():
    return jsonify({'output_string': "WORKS"})

# Merge the Flask app into Connexion's app
app.app = flask_app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
    

Line app.app = flask_app is there to embed the Flask application (flask_app) into the Connexion application (app in this case). This is needed because Connexion is a wrapper around Flask.
When you create a Connexion app, it manages its own Flask instance internally, and so to add custom routes (such as those defined using Flask decorators), you need to tell Connexion to use the Flask app instance that you are working with.
Without this line, Connexion would not recognize the @flask_app.route() routes because it would be working with a different Flask instance internally. With it, both your custom routes and Connexion’s routing and validation will work together.

This does not work for me. The code in this answer still gives me a 500 Internal Server Error, unless I provide a operationId in the spec.
